# ActionLink doesn't work

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something really stupid. Please have a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my `ActionLink`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","UserProfile", new { id = Model.ApplicationUserId },null)
```

When I click this it throws the bad request exception and also I noticed the url is

```
https://localhost:44304/UserProfile/Edit/92b1347c-c9ec-4728-8dff-11bc9f935d0b
```

not

```
https://localhost:44304/UserProfile/Edit?userId=92b1347c-c9ec-4728-8dff-11bc9f935d0b
```

I have a `HTTPGET` Edit method in my controller and it takes `UserId`. When I pass the route values manually it works.Please help me.
 Your help is much appreciated and someday, will pay it forward. 
Thanks!
Cheers!

Comment: Post your code for the Edit action method on the UserProfile controller. Not sure if you expect the parameter name to be `id` or `userId`, and also need to know what type the argument is.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Changing it to UserId totally worked. I thought 'id' is just a temp name that will match later to whatever in the method parameter . Guess I'm totally wrong.

Comment: Put the Controller Action too. You not only didn't place the Error but also didn't show your controller side!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameter you are expecting is `userId`, then use the `@Html.ActionLink` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","UserProfile", new { userId = Model.ApplicationUserId },null)
```

If you pass the parameter with name `id`, then the MVC will route like you mentioned:

```
https://localhost:44304/UserProfile/Edit/92b1347c-c9ec-4728-8dff-11bc9f935d0b
```

Which is great, but your method should be something expecting the parameter with the appropriate name:

```
// GET: /UserProfile/Edit/{id}
public ActionResult Edit(String id){


     //your code
     return View();
}
```

If you have some time, check out this [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) with a lot more details.

Comment: Wow! I thought 'id' is just a temp name that will match later to whatever in the method parameter . Guess I'm totally wrong and thanks heaps for this :)

Comment: It happened to me also when I started with MVC :D @RandikaWijekoon Glad I could help

Comment: No down vote :) . Just the tick . I was so eager to tick even before the 5 min. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

You need change parameter for your controller action Edit from  userId to id - best variant.

```
public Edit(int id)
{
}
```

Or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","UserProfile", new { userId = Model.ApplicationUserId },null)
```